# Computer components which have unique ID

Tags: windows-7

What are the computer parts that has a unique ID? Be it software or hardware. 
For example, IP Address. And the MAC ID in the NIC.
Unique ID's that could be used by bad sites to distinguish you from the rest of the crowd.

Edit: Or anything that cannot be changed. Anything that is embedded in the hardware that cannot be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a simple answer to this question.  IP addresses change constantly and [MAC addresses can be changed](http://www.google.com/search?q=change%20mac%20address).  Motherboards and other components often have a programmed identifier like a serial number, but I don't believe there is any kind of standard to access them from software, and it's certainly nothing a website would be able to access to identify you.

The best a website can do to identify you without your knowledge is through your IP address or by setting a cookie and tracking that. However, your IP can change (especially if you are a laptop hopping across different wi-fi networks), and you can clear your cookies.  Flash provides some storage for Flash applets but you can clear this as well.

Comment: thanks for the enlightenment but I believe that doesn't answer the question: Computer components which have unique ID

Comment: If the OEM has set the motherboard serial number into the BIOS it can be accessed via WMI.

Comment: @user: He's saying that nothing has a unique id that can't be changed. MAC address can be spoofed, IP address changes constantly, etc.